# python running lessc command

Tags: python, less

I have the following command 
lessc lessc xyz.less > xyz.css

I want to run that command in python for which i have written this code

```
   try:
        project_path = settings.PROJECT_ROOT
        less_path = os.path.join(project_path, "static\\less")
        css_path = os.path.join(project_path, "static\\css")
    except Exception as e:
        print traceback.format_exc()
    less_file = [f for f in os.listdir(less_path) if isfile(join(less_path, f))]
    for files in less_file:
        file_name = os.path.splitext(files)[0]
        cmd = '%s\%s > %s\%s' % (less_path, files, css_path, file_name + '.css')
        p = subprocess.Popen(['lessc', cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

but it gives error windowerror 2 cannot find the path specifies

Comment: Looks like the backslashes in `'%s\%s > %s\%s'` should be doubled (or use a raw string).

Comment: Can you please elaborate because double slashes do not work. Gives the same error

Comment: this is cmd value                                        'D:\\Muneeb\\Inpired Latest 4-7-2014\\inspired-redesign\\webapp\\inspired\\static\\less\\alerts.less > D:\\Muneeb\\Inpired Latest 4-7-2014\\inspired-redesign\\webapp\\inspired\\static\\css\\alerts.css'

Comment: I seem to recall that output redirection like that doesn't work with `subprocess`. I'm not sure, check the docs.

Comment: on running os.system() gives the error..... The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that 'lessc' is in your path, you could try using the full path to lessc instead.

You don't need to use shell style redirection with Popen like this, check the [subprocess.Popen docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)

Here is an example of how to do it without shell redirection:

```
import subprocess

lessc_command = '/path/to/lessc'
less_file_path = '/path/to/input.less'
css_file_path = '/path/to/output.css'
with open(css_file_path, 'w') as css_file:
    less_process = subprocess.Popen([lessc_command, less_file_path], stdout=css_file)
    less_process.communicate()
```